# determine truthy value for array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
var promises = [true,false,true,true,false];
```

What could be the best way to determine the truthy resultant
 from all values?

I can use `forEach` or `for in` but is there any other better way?

I am not using underscore or lodash but using jQuery.

E.g. in case above the result will be `false`.

Basically truthy resultant is AND operation on all values.

Comment: `.filter` could be a valid solution, in my opinion, whatever is the output you are expecting (which is unclear). After the edit, `.every` or `.some` are probably the fastest and cleanest way to accomplish the result.

Comment: Please define "truthy value resultant from all values".

Comment: Do you want to know if all the values are truthy or if any of them are truthy?  See [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), like so

```js
var promises = [true,false,true,true,false];
//var promises = [true,true,true,true,true];

var isTrue = promises.every(function (el) {
  return el === true;
})

console.log(isTrue);
```

Answer (score 2):

A little fun using recursivity:

```
function truthy (a) {
    return function aux (a, i) {
        return i === a.length || !!a[i] && aux(a, ++i);
    }(a, 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
truthy([]); // true
truthy([true]); // true
truthy([true, 0]); // false
truthy([true, '']); // false
```

Comment: Further interesting tests : `truthy([]); // true` but `truthy([null]); // false` . Meanwhile, undefined variables get handled differently. For example : `var somevar; truthy([somevar]); // false` while `truthy([someothervar])` throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: someothervar is not defined`.  Seems philosophical to debate whether an empty array is true while an array with only null entry is false, but more pragmatic to determine whether a "not defined" reference in array should be anticipated as possible array member and cast as FALSE, or if input of this "type" should fail at lower-level

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure to understand :-| `undefined` variable and `ReferenceError` are different things.

Comment: It's okay. Turns out the ReferenceError was being thrown at the point of  array instantiation, not within the truthy function, so it never actually reaches the truthy function because of the ReferenceError. So the idea that a member of the array could be an undefined and undeclared variable reference ( like `[someNewVar]` ) that the truthy function would need to anticipate handling isn't actually possible, since trying to create/update an array with such a variable fails before that array can be used elsewhere.